# ng-model from angular ng-file-upload for mongodb name of file uploaded

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, multer, ng-file-upload

Hello i have a problem with upload photo in mean stack by rest api. Upload already works fine but i have question of how in my solution pass name of file uploaded to mongodb.  here is my code for upload and api i use two api's for one form one for page desc title another for upload it good decision? or it better to do with one api for page? upload works file upload on submit form but in mongodb featuredImage is null. How to pass  name to mongodb for upload im using ng-file-upload where i can use ng-model="pageContent.featuredImage" ??

form.html

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"  rows="15" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="pageContent.content"></textarea>
    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"
             accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB"
             ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">
```

controller

```
        .controller('PagesAddEditCtrl',['$scope','$log','Upload','$window','$timeout', 'PagesFactory', '$routeParams', '$location', 'flashMessageService','$filter', function($scope, $log,Upload,$window,$timeout, PagesFactory, $routeParams, $location, flashMessageService, $filter) {
      $scope.pageContent = {};
      $scope.pageContent._id = $routeParams.id;
      $scope.heading = "Add a New Page";
      $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
          data: {file: file},
        });
        file.upload.then(function (response) {
          $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
          });
        }, function (response) {
          if (response.status > 0)
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
        }
  $scope.savePage = function(){
    PagesFactory.savePage($scope.pageContent).then(
      function(){
        flashMessageService.setMessage("Page Saved Successfully");
        $location.path('/pages')
      },
      function(){
        $log.error('error saving data');
      }
    );
  };
}]);
```

API

```
    router.post('/pages/add', function(req,res){
    var page = new Page({
        title:req.body.title,
        url:req.body.url,
        content:req.body.content,
        menuIndex: req.body.menuIndex,
        featuredImage: req.body.featuredImage,
        date:new Date(Date.now())
    });

    page.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
            return res.send(200, page);
        }else{
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
    });
});
```

page.model.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Page = new Schema({
        title: String,
        url: {type:String, index:{unique:true}},
        content: String,
        menuIndex: Number,
        featuredImage: String,
        date: Date  
    });
    var Page = mongoose.model('Page', Page);
    module.exports=Page;
```

node server

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null,  file.originalname)
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');
/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
      console.log('test');
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
          });
});
```

Comment: Where is `Upload.upload` defined in your frontend? Is it a library, if so, which?

Comment: @Brian He is using [ng-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ng-file-upload/info).

Comment: Ah, the title.. :-).

Answer (score 1):

Send the name as a separate part in the `form/multipart`:

```
  $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
      data: {file: file,
             name: file.name},
    });
```

For more information on the properties of files, see [MDN JavaScrip Web API Reference - File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Comment: and how i can use name to save it in mongodb when for page content i have another api?